# Counting Everything Besides Characters in Java

Tags: java

I need to print every character except letters. (commas, spaces, ect.) and display them. Here is the code thus far,

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    String a = "elephant";
    String b = "ElEphAnt";
    String c = "This is a string.";
    String d = "i R gr8, u R gr8";
    int ucounter = 0;
    int lcounter = 0;
    int dcounter = 0;
    int ocounter = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++)
    {
        if (Character.isUpperCase(a.charAt(i)))
            ucounter++;
        if (Character.isLowerCase(a.charAt(i)))
            lcounter++;
        if (Character.isDigit(a.charAt(i)))
            dcounter++;
    }
    System.out.println("String: " + a );
    System.out.println("\n");
    System.out.println("\tlowercase: %d, uppercase: %d, digit: %d, other: " +ucounter);



}
```

I am having a small issue getting them to print out the numbers after calculating them, but that is a separate issue I will solve on my own. I have perused the forums and cannot seem to find how I count white space and special characters. I am only allowed to use `length()` and `charAt()` for this. What is the `Character.is??` for special characters? Or is there even one?

Comment: maybe checking out the Ascii table will help

Comment: You could count everything that's not a lower case letter and not an upper case letter and not a digit as a special character.

Comment: for white space you can use `Character.isWhitespace`. Also print statement should be like this: `System.out.format("lowercase: %d, uppercase: %d, digit: %d, other: %d", lcounter, ucounter, dcounter, ocounter);`.

Comment: @Barend that sounds like a good idea! However, I am not entirely sure on how I would go about doing that.

Comment: @NaughtyBear you can combine two `Character.isXXX()` tests inside an if-clause with the `&&` (and) operator. You can invert a check with the `!` (not) operator. With these two building blocks, you should be able to make it work.

Comment: @YoungHobbit Thanks! For some reason a part of me believed that I really needed to do '+ucounter' and such.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of just using `if`'s, use `if/else` combinations, so that you can make sure you're always only running into *one* matching case. Then, use `Character.isWhitespace` to detect white space, and finally `!Character.isLetter` (note the `!`) to detect everything except letters.

It's important that you do this with `if/else`s or else the last test will match for digits, commas, whitespace, etc. too.

From class documentation for [java.lang.Character.isLetter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetter-int-):

> A character is considered to be a letter if its general category type, provided by getType(codePoint), is any of the following:
>
> - [UPPERCASE_LETTER](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#UPPERCASE_LETTER)
> - [LOWERCASE_LETTER](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#LOWERCASE_LETTER)
> - [TITLECASE_LETTER](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#TITLECASE_LETTER)
> - [MODIFIER_LETTER](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#MODIFIER_LETTER)
> - [OTHER_LETTER](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#OTHER_LETTER)

Comment: So it has some formatting issues when I print it out, but for the most part, it worked! Thank you very much. ^_^ Just in case you believe I am doing something different than what I should, I put 'System.out.printf(" ");' in the else statement for each.

Answer (score 1):

You can use !(Character.isLetter(c) || Character.isDigit(c)) operations. This will print non-alphanumeric characters.

```
public class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String str = "fkgajsf783 yrW^R^.,,";

        //str = str.replaceAll("\\s", ""); // if you do not want to white space, use this line;

        int count = 0;
        for (char c : str.toCharArray()) {
            if (!(Character.isLetter(c) || Character.isDigit(c))) {
                System.out.println(c);
                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(count);

    }
}
```

prints:

```
     // White space
^
^
.
,
,
6
```

Comment: what about the white space. You can add that also in the condition, for getting all the special chars only.

Comment: @YoungHobbit, if you do not want to print white speace, you should add str = str.replaceAll("\\s", ""); before for-loop to remove all white speaces.

Comment: The OP wants to count them. That is why i said.